# Ontologies on the notarial domain

Tags: ontology

I am completely new to ontologies and have been doing some research on representing notarial deeds in the historical domain (ie: old acts) using ontologies and RDF to create a knowledge graph.

I am having a hard time finding an ontology on this particular domain. Did anyone encounter such ontologies?

Usually in such documents one will find parties involved in an event such as a will, donation etc... These will include also dates, items involved and relationships between the parties. I thought about creating the ontology myself but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if something already exists

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `charters`? See this search

https://www.google.com/search?q=chartex+charter+annotation